# Java campo apenas com números

Tags: java, regex, validação, joptionpane

Estou fazendo um cadastro de medico para um teste de sistema de hospital e gostaria de saber como validar o campo **CRM**.
Trata-se de uma variavel *double*, quero que o campo do **Joptionpane** aceite apenas numeros em **CRM**, ja tentei diversas formas como *regular expression* etc e nada deu certo..

```
public static void cadastroMedico(){
    int lista=1;
    do{
        acho=0;
        codigoMedic=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o código do médico"));
        if(medicos.size()>0)
            for(int i = 0;i<medicos.size();i++){
                if(codigoMedic==medicos.get(i).getIdMedico())
                    acho=1;
            }
            if(acho == 1)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Médico já cadastrado","Aviso",1);        
    }while(acho==1);

    nomemed = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o nome do Médico: ");
    while(!matchesOnlyText(nomemed)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você não pode inserir números no campo nome.");
        nomemed = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o nome do Médico: ");
    }

    **crm = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o CRM do Médico: "));**


    setor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o setor do Médico: ");
    while(!matchesOnlyText(setor)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você não pode inserir números no campo setor.");
        setor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o setor do Médico:");
    }
}
```

Comment: Quando diz que quer validar o CRM está a dizer validação de formato ou validação de existência de um médico com este número de CRM?

Comment: No caso estou falando da validação de formato, mas a parte mais prioritária no caso seria "quero que o campo do Joptionpane aceite apenas numeros em CRM".

Comment: Não estou a encontrar o formato de um numero CRM, podia indicar?

Comment: Um exemplo de CRM : 27134.

Comment: porque precisa de ser double?

Comment: Regex para só serem válidos digitos ^[0-9]+$

Comment: Tens razão, mudei a Variável CRM para Int, porem do mesmo jeito segue sem funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Veja se é isto que pretende :**

```
String input;
int crm;
do {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o CRM do Médico: ");
    if (input.matches("^[0-9]+$")) {
        crm = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.println("CRM : " + crm);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Por favor insira um CRM válido");
    }
} while (!input.matches("^[0-9]+$"));
```